# What is the use of html-loader and how it work's in Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-loader, webpack-html-loader

I was learning webpack and I came across `loaders`,The defination of `loaders` says that it transform your code,so that it can be included inside the javascript `bundle`.

**But,How html-loader works?**

The `html-loader` defination says that it exports html as String (What does it mean).

it also says that every loadable attributes (for example `<img src="image.png"` is imported as `require('./image.png')`,and you may need to specify loader for images in your configuration (`file-loader` or `url-loader`), What does it mean.

I want to know, what actually html-loader do. Does it convert `html` into String or it just convert the `img` tag to `require`. How all this work together.

Can someone explain in detail.

Comment: Same Problem . If You Can Found It?

Answer (score 7):

I'm answering your questions in a different sequence for I believe this is a more logical sequence for understanding the usage of the `html-loader`.

There are two underlying questions that I'm going to answer first.

Q. What type of asset webpack understands by default?

A. By default webpack only understands JavaScript.

Q. What should we do if we want to work with other types of assets (namely HTML, CSS, images, etc.)?

A. We must use *loaders* and *plugins* to expand webpack's functionality.

In other words, loaders and plugins allow us to work with *static assets* in webpack.

Q. What does it mean to export HTML as string?

A. You need to remember that HTML and JavaScript are two different things. If you want to manipulate the DOM using JavaScript, you do that through APIs, for example, when you write

```
const p = document.createElement("p");
document.body.appendChild(p);
```

You are using the *Document* Object to write to an HTML file. You can also do something like this:

```
const html = `
  <h1>heading level 1</h1>
`;
const header = document.createElement("header");
header.innerHTML = html;

document.body.appendChild(header);
```

The *string* assigned to the `html` variable is what's called an *HTML string*. Simple put, a string that contains HTML markup.

This is part of what the `html-loader` do: it reads your HTML files and returns their contents as HTML strings that can be understand by JavaScript and used by APIs.

The `html-loader` also translates *every loadable attribute* to `require()` calls. Again, because JavaScript doesn't understand HTML related syntax such as `src`, `href`, etc., but it understands the `require()` syntax, which is JavaScript related syntax.

For more information on APIs see [Client-side web APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs).

Q. What does it mean (that you may have to specify a loader for images in your configuration)?

A. If your `.html` file has an `img` inside it, the image will be required but, again, webpack only understands JavaScript by default. Therefore, you'll have to set up a loader for allowing webpack to process your image.

Q. How the `html-loader` works?

A. Simplifying, it will read the contents of you `.html` file and, if it finds loadable attributes on the elements, it will translate them into `require()` calls. The URL passed as an argument to the `require()` function can reference a simple address (when an `href` attribute is translated into a `require()` call, for instance) and, in this situation, you won't need to set up an additional loader; Or it can reference an image (when a `src` is translated into a `require()` call, for example) and, in this situation, since webpack don't understand images by default, you'll have to configure a loader (the `file-loader`).

**Note**: Since webpack 5, webpack uses [Asset Modules](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/) for loading images. Therefore, you don't need to set up additional loaders for handling images.

Answer (score 0):

Since webpack completely overhauled how it works in 5.0. "Exports HTML as a string" is not exactly the best description of a use case anymore. It used to be that one would chain html-loader with extract-loader and file-loader to emit html. Now I would use it to parse html for whatever reason.
https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/extract-loader/

Answer (score -1):

As you can read from the https://webpack.js.org/loaders/html-loader/

This does more than just converting into strings.

You can preprocess the htmls like adding values to variables,
You can apply filters,
... to name a few

```js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        loader: 'html-loader',
        options: {
          attributes: {
            list: [
              {
                // Tag name
                tag: 'img',
                // Attribute name
                attribute: 'src',
                // Type of processing, can be `src` or `scrset`
                type: 'src',
              },
              {
                // Tag name
                tag: 'img',
                // Attribute name
                attribute: 'srcset',
                // Type of processing, can be `src` or `scrset`
                type: 'srcset',
              },
              {
                tag: 'img',
                attribute: 'data-src',
                type: 'src',
              },
              {
                tag: 'img',
                attribute: 'data-srcset',
                type: 'srcset',
              },
              {
                // Tag name
                tag: 'link',
                // Attribute name
                attribute: 'href',
                // Type of processing, can be `src` or `scrset`
                type: 'src',
                // Allow to filter some attributes
                filter: (tag, attribute, attributes, resourcePath) => {
                  // The `tag` argument contains a name of the HTML tag.
                  // The `attribute` argument contains a name of the HTML attribute.
                  // The `attributes` argument contains all attributes of the tag.
                  // The `resourcePath` argument contains a path to the loaded HTML file.

                  if (/my-html\.html$/.test(resourcePath)) {
                    return false;
                  }

                  if (!/stylesheet/i.test(attributes.rel)) {
                    return false;
                  }

                  if (
                    attributes.type &&
                    attributes.type.trim().toLowerCase() !== 'text/css'
                  ) {
                    return false;
                  }

                  return true;
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

The above code is as taken from the link, this is an example of filtering.

Alternatively, you can also use this plugin `html-webpack-plugin`

Comment: Can you tell me does html-loader really converts the whole HTML file into JavaScript String